# Empty but already deleted answers don't appear "deleted"

Tags: bug, deleted-answers, quality-filter, late-answers

When going through [new answers to old question](https://stackoverflow.com/tools/new-answers-old-questions) it's normally pretty easy to tell if an answer has been deleted already or not. A couple of times now I've seen totally blank answers that have already been deleted, but don't look like they have.

[Example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9067566/168175):
[image: example image]

It's *not* a race where the answer has been deleted after the page loaded on my machine, the answer in that screenshot was deleted 4 hours before I took the screenshot, my machine here has an uptime of < 2 hours.

The problem in this instance (and previous instances I've spotted) is the OP has posted something like:

```
<uses-permission
       android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

but without any markup to indicate it as code. This results in an effectively empty body.

Can this be fixed either by:

1. Reject the answer entirely at the quality filter level - as it stands it's effectively an empty answer that happens to have a non-zero string length. It would have been better if this example were not posted at all.
2. Failing that show that it's been deleted in already in the list of answers somehow.

Comment: If the post is deleted anyway, and 10K users can get to the underlying text, does it really matter?

Comment: @RobertHarvey - It's moderately inconvenient to a fair number of people (everyone who views it there *has* to open the full post to see if it needs flagging or not) and it creates more work for both 10k users *and* mods that could have sensibly been avoided in the first place.

Comment: Another example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8138467/cannot-import-the-css-in-jsf-pages/9147348#9147348

Comment: It's not just empty posts - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1345454/wcf-cross-domain-policy-security-error/9267650#9267650 had a 100% code body, but still showed indistinguishably.